# bash sh script always executes regardless of parameter

Tags: bash

I have the following script

```
#!/bin/bash   
if [ $1=="1" ]
then
    echo $1
fi
```

Whenever I run ./myscript.sh 0 it still prints "0". I am not sure why? It prints whatever I type in because the if executes. What would I need to change?

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add proper **spaces**, i.e. **before** and **after** `==` inside if condition

```
#!/bin/bash   

if [ $1 == "1" ] 
then
    echo $1
fi
```